# Someone peeled an American flag sticker off of my truck. What do I do?

Tags: work-environment, united-states, human-resources, politics, security

I started a new job recently and I noticed one day that my American flag sticker had been removed from my truck's window. I am heavily suspicious that it may have occurred while I was at work, and would further indulge in saying I believe it was someone from my building.

How would I go about handling this situation? My first guess would be going to the security desk and ask if the cameras caught anything. Since I am a contractor, I don't know if I should report it to *my* company's HR department, or the company I'm currently working for's HR department.

Additionally, would it be wise to purchase another sticker, and should I inform my site's manager? It would be worth noting that the incident occurred at least a week before the election.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48297/discussion-on-question-by-matt-brennan-someone-peeled-an-american-flag-sticker-o).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Well ... that truly sucks.

Frankly, there's not much to be gained by complaining. You have no evidence that this happened at work, and won't be making any friends by reporting it.

If I were you, I would document that it happened, and just buy a new sticker. Keep a close eye on it and see if it happens again, and more importantly, if it happens at work.

If it does, go to HR, explain the situation, and show them the photos of when it happened the first time around. This way you actually have a case to present to them.

Comment: Should I report this to HR in the first place as documentation, or should I wait and see if it happens again?

Comment: @mattbrennan - I would simply take pictures. Do it on company property so that they can tell that's where you noticed it. Then buy a new sticker and make sure to check it's still there at the end of each workday. If it disappears .. you'll know, and can go to HR right away

Comment: Part of the question states "should report it to MY companies HR department, or the company I'm currently working for's HR department".  Your answer should also specify *which* HR should be told if it happens again.

Comment: It is worth noting that even if you knew it happened while you were at work, that doesn't implicate the people in your company unless you park in a place that only employees have access to. Could it be a visiting guest? A nearby company? Some random people walking by who have nothing to do with your company? Seems unlikely that the OP can really tie this back to co-workers unless there was video evidence implicating a specific person

Comment: @KevinWells The way my building is set up, only people who have business with my company would be able to access my vehicle.  It's sort of a large building in the middle of an off-ramp from the highway.  It could easily have been a visiting contractor, someone else from my building but not my company, or even maybe a visiting business partner.  There is alot of video surveillance where I park as well.

Comment: @Kevin Wells the important point, in my opinion ,is not _who_ perpetrated this vandalism (minor as it is) but _where_ it happened.  If this happened on a company maintained parking lot, I think that company should be informed even if it was done by some random guy off the street.

Comment: @AndreiROM Checking at the end of each workday only works if you also check at the beginning. ;)

Comment: Or, just escalate.  If someone tore your sticker off, and you truly cannot stand that this happened... *go out and buy two stickers!*  That'll show them!

Answer (score 90):

If I were the security manager, and you showed up to report a missing $2 sticker, I'd hand you $2 and send you on your way.

For all you know, it could have been dumb kids in your neighborhood, or **anywhere** you parked your vehicle.  You can replace the sticker, or not.  But don't expect anyone to go on a witchhunt over it.  Slashed tires, broken windshields, or similar are on a whole different level.

"Don't Sweat the Small Stuff" -- Richard Carlson

Comment: I would like to know why my comments were deleted here. They were valid and relevant to the answer. I'm not "reporting a missing sticker" I'm reporting an incident involving possible political targeting. I'd rather like to handle it so it doesn't continue and I find myself in a worse situation.

Comment: *shrug* wasn't my doing.  I didn't know they were gone til your comment just now

Comment: @MattBrennan No specific idea, but comments are not guaranteed to be permanent on any SE site.  They can always be deleted for whatever reason.  Any critical information should go into answers/questions, and any lengthy discussions should be held in chat.

Comment: If, as a security manager, you tell "Have $2, move along", I'd feel you don't care enough for security. He's not crying about the 2 bucks the sticker costs, but the fact of _not feeling secure_ at your premises. It's not the sticker - it's the fact _they did it_.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia I used to work for a company, with a name i wouldn't even have to finish for you to recognize, that provides in-home consumer entertainment.  I supported a fraud department.  Know what?  They'd turn cases over to the FBI.  The FBI doesn't even bother with cases less than $100 grand.  In short, one can't chase after everything.

Comment: @codenoir yes but that's a criminal case executed by a higher authority. My situation involves office disputes and tensions with my workspace. If I feel alienated in my work, and that affects my ability to perform my job as well as I should, It becomes a major issue. Is that not the point of HR, to help solve inter-persons disputes within the workplace?

Comment: The tension wasn't within your workspace, it was in the parking lot. You can't prove that your sticker actually disappeared on the premises, nor point to a possible suspect, nor give any allusion to a motive other than you *breathing*.  If it was all that bad, you could have (a) called the non-emergency number for the local police, (b) waited until the next morning for them to actually show up, (c) got a police report that they'd throw in the round file (d) spent an hour filing an insurance claim, and (e) wrote your local member of Congress, and Mr. Obama. I'm done, before this is deleted too.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia I think the *not feeling secure* line is a bit overblow, unless you assume that everybody who does something as minor as peeling a sticker will be involved also in more serious attacks. To put an example, if I forgot a book outside my car in the parking lot and found later that somebody had taken it(which is indeed a crime), I would not take that as a sign that the same person would assault and rob me in the same parking lot... In fact, I would say that it is not "a bit overblown", but rather quite a lot overblown. Try to use some common sense.

Comment: @SJuan76 the textbook example doesn't apply here in the slightest. They would have something to gain from taking the textbook, and it's not an inconvenience to pick up a text book like peeling a sticker off of someones car. Sure, I don't think someone is going to rob me because of this situation, but there are numerous other things that it can bring that can be avoided.

Comment: @MattBrennan Again, these are some huge leaps that you are doing for a single incident that just did involve a sticker being peeled. If you are really that worried ("numerous other things") and not just a drama king, request police protection. If I were that paranoid, I would say that the book was robbed by someone that is obsessed with me and was stalking me and is getting ready for "numerous other things that it can bring".  And BTW... how did **you** know that it was a textbook? I did not specify that, and that sounds very suspicious to me.

Comment: @SJuan76 Textbooks are associated with value and books so I assumed thats what you meant. And i would hardly consider "telling HR about something that happened"  a huge leap. I'm not trying to get any legal involvement, more so I want it documented in case something else happens. Otherwise every incident can just be considered isolated and nothing will be done.

Answer (score 26):

> I am heavily suspicious that it may have occurred while I was at work

Suspicious is one thing, proof is an altogether different thing.  I am not condoning vandalism, but unless you have proof that it was done at work then involving HR is the wrong thing to do as it establishes a baseline of

> Something bad happened to me, I don't know who perpetrated it but I am
>   blaming my coworkers even though I have no proof.

At most I would document it in a physical notebook somewhere, replace the sticker and keep an eye out for it being removed again *while you are at work*.  At that point you have actual evidence you can present to HR.

Answer (score 14):

> How would I go about handling this situation?

Report it to Security, Building Management and HR of the location where you have been working. Don't expect much - there's very little they can do.

They might have security video that could be reviewed, and if it shows the identity of the person who peeled off your sticker, you could choose to go to the police.

Unfortunately, the fact that you don't really know when or where it occurred makes it very unlikely for you to get any justice.

> Additionally, would it be wise to purchase another sticker, and should
>   I inform my sites manager?

Yes. Wait a bit then get your sticker, but inform your site manager now.

This sort of vandalism tends to be a drive-by or walk-by thing. Hopefully, it won't happen again.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a strong feeling that if you get a new sticker and somebody will remove it again, it might be worth installing a [video registrator (aka dashcam)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashcam) and perhaps not too obviously, so that if it happens again, the offender wouldn't see it and get scared off. If you happen to catch the sticker stealer on camera like this, you may have a very strong case to present to HR, but that's up to you.

Or perhaps you can install a fake dashcam which will spook the potential offenders and prevent them from taking down your sticker.

Comment: This is what I was going to write: replace the sticker + set up a camera. Until YOU have it recorded, you have nothing. No evidence on where it happened.

Comment: Thats a great suggestion. I will be buying one promptly in addition to the steps Andreil suggested.

Comment: Keep in mind that this might mean you spend a bunch of money on a camera, only to record a face you don't know. Making it obvious so people don't try might be more useful than hiding it in the hopes you know the person who did it.

Comment: I just looked up the prices, they seem to be in the range between 50 and 100 usd. This particular issue aside, it's still a very good investment, in case somebody pulls insurance fraud on you after an incident on the road. Wikipedia article describes its benefits. Additionally, I think you could still report the person to the police, although I doubt it would be seriously investigated, but if the quality is really good and the person is easily identifiable, who knows, maybe they'll get fined and their employer will find out about this.

Comment: I am unsure of OPs resources, but an old smartphone and laptop might do the trick (assuming you needed extra storage or advanced features). I have used this combo in the past as remote surveillance. Power might be the only issue.

Answer (score 3):

In times of high political tension, it's best to let it go.  There are some people feeling very hurt and scared, and the sources of their pain are rather attached to the flag.  You, I'm sure have your own reasons for displaying the flag, and it doesn't matter at this stage whether those reasons match some other people's. Some of the people feeling hurt are your colleagues, even your friends. You still need to get on with them.  I suggest that you replace it soon (as it obviously means a lot to you) but not immediately as that could be seen as provocative.

I have also seen a situation where a car was thought to have been damaged (expensive paint damage) in the work car park. The driver turned out to have been wrong and to have missed the fact that the damage had happened earlier and elsewhere.  Despite making only quiet enquiries they ended up fairly embarassed.  If they had made a fuss and then turned out to be wrong, smoothing things over would have been hard.